# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference in mvc

Tags: c#

```
@if ((ViewBag.DynamicFields.Length == 0 )||((ViewBag.DynamicFields as ICollection<ChampModel.DynamicFields>).Where(o => o.Active == false).Count() == (ViewBag.DynamicFields as ICollection<ChampModel.DynamicFields>).Count()))
{
    <div class="info">
    @Html.Label("Dynamic fields were not assigned to this table")</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you have a ViewBag property being nonexistent in your view.

See if there is a typo?

or just add check for null

```
 @if (((ViewBag.DynamicFields == null) ||(ViewBag.DynamicFields.Length == 0 )||((ViewBag.DynamicFields as ICollection<ChampModel.DynamicFields>).Where(o => o.Active == false).Count() == (ViewBag.DynamicFields as ICollection<ChampModel.DynamicFields>).Count()))
```

Comment: What is a typo?

Comment: @KiruthigaSankar spelling mistake.

Comment: Did you add the value in the controller?